# Criteria to prove that a map is a tempered distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

There is any simple sufficient condition to determine if a function is a tempered distribution?
For example, given the map :
$$
F \phi = \int_\epsilon^\infty \! \frac {\phi(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
I can prove that this is a tempered distribution with consideration about topology (for every epsilon this distribution is associated with an $L^2$ function, ecc..), but how can I do it using the definition?

Comment: Are you looking for something along the lines of: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ is locally integrable, therefore it defines a distribution, the function grows at most polynomially, hence it's tempered?

Comment: Yes, but i have a doubt the last passages: slowly increasing function => is tempered; how can you rigorously prove it? It is sufficient to say that the integral converges?

Comment: No, that's not sufficient. You also must show that the such-defined linear functional on the Schwartz space is continuous. Now, $$\left\lvert\int_{\varepsilon}^\infty \frac{\phi(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx\right\rvert \leqslant \lVert\phi\rVert_\infty \int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}+ \int_1^\infty \lvert\phi(x)\rvert\,dx\leqslant 2\lVert\phi\rVert_\infty+ \left(\sup_{\xi\in\mathbb{R}} \lvert \xi^2\phi(\xi)\rvert\right)\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} = 2\lVert\phi\rVert_\infty + \sup_{\xi\in\mathbb{R}} \lvert \xi^2\phi(\xi)\rvert,$$ and you have your bound in terms of two of the seminorms defining the topology.

Comment: Great, thanks! 
But, Sorry to bother you, one last question: the inequality doesn't have to be verified for every seminorm $\|~\|_{m,n}$ ?

Comment: No, a linear form $\lambda$ on the Schwartz space is continuous if and only if there are a finite number of those seminorms and a constant $C$ such that $$\lvert\lambda(\phi)\rvert \leqslant C\sum_{\nu=1}^n p_\nu(\phi),$$ where each of the $p_\nu$ is one of the $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{m,n}$. If you define the seminorms as $$\lVert\phi\rVert_{m,n} = \sup \left\{ \lvert x^m\partial^n\phi(x)\rvert : x\in\mathbb{R} \right\},$$ then always one seminorm suffices. Note that for example the derivatives of $\delta$ don't satisfy such an inequality for the seminorms not involving the derivatives of $\phi$

Comment: of sufficiently high order, yet they are continuous, because for seminorms involving the derivatives of high enough order, you have such an inequality.

Comment: Sorry :(, one seminorm suffices since?